# shell script to check for multiple files with different names

Tags: bash, unix

I am creating a script to check for 3 files in Directory, take the count of rows in them and mail if the rows exist.I have to send only one mail if either of these files have count, I am ending up sending 3 mails.

For Ex. I have these files

```
process_date.txt
thread_date.txt
child_date.txt
```

Iam doing something like

```
$1= process_date.txt
$2= thread_date.txt
$3= child_date.txt

if [ -f $1 ]
then
count1=`wc-l < $1`
if $count1 -ne 0 then mailx abc.com
fi
fi

if [ -f $2 ]
then
count2=`wc-l < $2`
if $count2 -ne 0 then mailx abc.com
fi
fi 

if [ -f $3 ]
then
count3=`wc-l < $3`
if $count3 -ne 0 then mailx abc.com
fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your script in a function and use `return` command after every `mailx`, like this:

```
send_one_mail() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]
  then
    count1=$(wc -l < "$1")
    if [ $count1 -ne 0 ]
    then
      mailx abc.com
      return
    fi
  fi

  # etc. for other conditions

}

send_one_mail process_date.txt thread_date.txt child_date.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

As you stated your question, it seems you only need to check whether at least one of the files is non-empty: you don't need to count the number of rows. In Bash, you may use the `[[ -s file ]]` test to exactly test whether `file` exists and is non-empty. So you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -s $1 ]] || [[ -s $2 ]] || [[ -s $3 ]]; then
    mailx abc.com
fi
```

More generally, you can have the mail sent if at least one of the files given as arguments exists and is non-empty:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file; do
    if [[ -s $file ]]; then
        mailx abc.com
        break
    fi
done
```

You'll call this as

```
scriptname process_date.txt thread_date.txt child_date.txt
```

Comment: @ gniourf_gniourf, I need to send only one mail(if the file has records. i.e if 3 files have records or 2 files or 1) and it has to be a common mail.Mail should not be replicated.

Comment: @Naaz: But this script only sends 1 mail, due to the`break` command. You can test it by replacing `mailx abc.com` by `echo abc.com`

Comment: @Naaz: And if you want to get ultra-compact, gniourf_gniourf's 2nd script can be condensed down to a single line: `for f;do [[ -s $f ]] && { mailx abc.com; break; } done`

Comment: Thank You, thanks for resolving the situation @gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if [ -f $1 ]
then
    count1=`wc -l < $1`
fi

if [ -f $2 ]
then
    count2=`wc -l < $2` 
fi 

if [ -f $3 ]
then
    count3=`wc -l < $3`
fi


if [ $count1 -ne 0 -o $count2 -ne 0 -o $count3 -ne 0 ]
then
    mailx abc.com
fi
```